# Getting Crashes but showing wrong/old Version number in Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting, bitcode

- Bitcode: No
- Firebase Crashlytics: 8.5.0 (Latest)

I integrated the Firebase Crashlytics in my app on version 3.1.8. On the testing device, it reports me correctly. but when I see the report of online users it reporting me crashes but the version is wrong. as you can see in the screenshot

[image]

Now I am not able to download dSYMs from app connect because bitcode is not enabled and I cannot enable it due to pod `MobileVLCKit` and my local machine don't have 3.1.0 (1).
I am confused about how to deal with it.

I have uploaded 2 more versions(3.1.9 and 3.2.0) but it's showing the same results. strangely my dashboard shows the correct version when I open detail its showing wrong

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not bugs on old versions? People that haven't updated yet their app?

Comment: yes @Larme, users are using the latest build. as you can see I have attached another screenshot. where it saying "Need investigation". it shows the correct version. but when I open detail and go to the actual crash report list. it's showing me 3.1.0(1)

Comment: Yes @Larme I am sure because in old version crashlytics was not even integrated. previously it doesn't even have any firebase analytics or crashlytics. i added firebase in 3.1.8 onwards